# Showing a error msg as while using this below mensioned relative xpath "is not a valid XPath expression"

Tags: xpath, relative-path

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-fb' AND @title='Log in with Facebook']")).click();
```

Comment: Replace `AND` with `and`

Comment: Although I always use lowercase anyway, I was not aware that xpath was case-sensitive.